# using :new and :old referencing different tables in SQL

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, psql, database-trigger

Revising for a uni exam. A question states:

Write an SQL command to create a trigger in table Permission. The
trigger should add one to the numberOfPermissions in table File for a
file, after each time a new permission row is entered into table
Permission with that file’s name.

[here's a list of the tables provided](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfrnh.png)

I've got everything down except one line, the WHERE line. How would I specify the :new value to a different table? It needs to read the new value as a the fileName column coming from the Permissions table, but I'm not sure how to do that. I've tried it in ways such as :Permissions.new.fileName etc but I always get an unspecified error around the "." point.

```
    CREATE TRIGGER newTrig
AFTER INSERT ON Permission
BEGIN
UPDATE File
SET numberOfPermissions = numberOfPermissions+1
WHERE File.name = :new.fileName
END;
```

Comment: I'm using Oracle

Answer (score 4):

When  I run your trigger creation code [in this db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6f4e46a918f9d376e930991f00f3d696), it gives me :

```
ORA-04082: NEW or OLD references not allowed in table level triggers
```

What happens is that you have omitted the `FOR EACH ROW` option in the declaration of the trigger. Because of that, Oracle believes that you want a *table* level trigger, which is executed once per *statement* (whereas a *row* level trigger is executed once for each row inserted).

As a single statement can result in multiple rows being inserted (eg : `INSERT INTO ... AS SELECT ...`), Oracle does not allow you to access `:NEW` and `:OLD` references in table level triggers.

Adding the `FOR EACH ROW` option to your trigger definition will make it a row level trigger, that is allowed to access `:NEW` and `:OLD` references.

```
CREATE TRIGGER newTrig
AFTER INSERT ON Permission
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE File 
    SET numberOfPermissions = numberOfPermissions+1 
    WHERE File.name = :new.fileName;
END;
```

PS : you were also missing a semi-colon at the end of the `UPDATE` statement.

---

Unrelated PS :

```
> create table USER ( x number);
ORA-00903: invalid table name

> create table FILE ( x number);
ORA-00903: invalid table name
```

=> It is usually not a good idea to create tables whose names are reserved words, this can sometimes lead to tricky errors.

Answer (score 0):

Trigger knows which records should get update, so you can use ":OLD" pointer.
Try something like this:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER newTrig
    AFTER INSERT ON Permission
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        UPDATE File
        SET numberOfPermissions = numberOfPermissions+1 
        WHERE name = :old.fileName
    END;
```